# Showing div while javascript code is executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div that I need to show during javascript code execution:

```
ShowLoadingBar = function() {
    $('#loading').dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 250,
        height: 60,
        title: "Processing...",
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").attr("style","display:none");
}
```

But when calling this it does not display while javascript is executing.
How do I fix this?

Comment: setTimeout(function () { ShowMenuClickLoadingBar(); }, 100); still only shows the div after execution is done

Comment: try to hide the div after the javascript code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript executes the code sequentially. You don't have multiple threads or something...

So if you want to display something and then run some js processing or ajax call, run the code to display the dialog first!

If this doesn't help, try setTimeout(...), this should actually enable you to run something asynchronous to the normal execution.

Comment: I've tried setTimeout(function () { ShowMenuClickLoadingBar(); }, 100); but it still does not work